# Using NPM token from Google Secret Manager during Cloud Build process

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, package.json, google-secret-manager

Can Google Cloud Build use an NPM token during the install process?

I'm using a private NPM package across applications and I know we can [place the token within an .npmrc file](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#using_private_modules)

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN>
```

But I would like to keep the token out of the codebase(s) and use SM for what it's for.

But this doesn't seem possible and the docs do not seem to cover this.

Comment: I believe you can set the token value as an environment variable `NPM_TOKEN` per https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow#set-the-token-as-an-environment-variable-on-the-cicd-server. In that case, you can use the native Cloud Build + Secret Manager integration to inject the value: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets

Comment: And if the `NPM_TOKEN` solution doesn't work, you can still use Secret Manager and CLoud Build to load your token, write your .npmrc file with a script and then run your build. Let us know what you tried and where you are blocked.

Comment: Wow, thank you both. I will certainly update in full detail.

Comment: Hi @BenRacicot, have you tried the solutions? Thanks

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar I'm getting help to setup Secret Manager. Will certainly reply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to get experienced help for Secret Manager for this and it still took over 20 hours.

Assuming you possess general knowledge of GCP and Secret Manager and have your NPM token on-hand (found at npmjs.com/settings/USERNAME/tokens)

1. Create a Secret Manager secret named `NPM_TOKEN` with its value
   being the private NPM package's **automation** `token`
2. Within the cloudbuild.yaml build process create an .npmrc

```
steps:
  - name: bash
    args: ['-c', 'echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$$NPM_TOKEN > .npmrc'] <-- main takeaway
    secretEnv: ['NPM_TOKEN']
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args: ['gcloud', 'app', 'deploy']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/NPM_TOKEN/versions/latest
      env: 'NPM_TOKEN'
```

Now the cloud build process has an `NPM_TOKEN` value to pull in the private NPM package.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, posting the solution proposed by sethvargo and guillaume blaquiere for visibility.

You can set the token value as an environment variable, [`NPM_TOKEN`](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow#set-the-token-as-an-environment-variable-on-the-cicd-server). In that case, you can use the native Cloud Build + Secret Manager integration to inject the value: cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets

If the `NPM_TOKEN` solution doesn't work, you can still use the Secret Manager and Cloud Build to load your token, write your `.npmrc` file with a script and then run your build.